# Had pre installed Windows 8.1 in HP laptop but then I replaced it with another OS but now I want to reinstall it

Tags: windows, reinstall

I bought a HP laptop with Windows 8.1 pre-installed but then I installed Linux on it used it for some time. But Now I want Windows 8.1 (activated) back on my laptop.

I read somewhere that I can have it back as long as I use the same version of Windows 8.1 and there is some option when asked for product key something like reinstalling or something.

Is that true? Can I do something like that?

Comment: Don't quote me on that but you should be able to install Windows 10 or even 11 if supported (unlikely) and it'll activate with the same key.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, no longer: https://liliputing.com/microsoft-ends-free-upgrades-from-windows-7-or-8-to-windows-10-or-11/ If you *must* run 8.1, consider doing so in a VM, such as VirtulaBox, on Linux.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It seems like the original poster is being vague about whether they remember if they have the “product key” which might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your answers, I solved it.

First I downloaded the Windows 8.1 single language iso from official microsoft website.

Flashed a USB Drive, installed it in my PC. (Skipped the product key step in installation)

Then I used " wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey " in cmd.

And I got my product key, used it to activated.

It should work for all PCs that came with pre installed windows. I also have an old laptop which has a sticker under the battery with product key mentioned on it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 is out of support, but you can look in Microsoft Downloads to see if they still have a Windows 8.1 ISO to download. They are removing these downloads but do check.

Otherwise, is the recovery partition intact? You can reinstall Windows 8.1 from that.

If there is no Microsoft source, you can try eBay for a Windows 8.1 DVD with Key and with right of return.  I did this with Vista and the VM is still running fine. Activation has never been an issue.

Also if the machine properly supported Windows 8.1, it should run Windows 10. You can try that. I did that with my own Windows 8.1 X230 laptop and it continues to run. You can easily get a Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft so this may be worth a try.

The Microsoft Licensing Server has (should still have) the key, so if you get Windows 8.1 installed it will activate.

Comment: Or you can just use The Pirate Bay. If you own the license there is nothing to stop you downloading the ISO.

Comment: @davidgo It seems like the original poster is being vague about whether they remember if they have the “product key” which might be a problem.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I thought HP Laptops came with OEM keys embedded ?

Comment: @davidgo Well, you know better than me! I could be mistaken.